# set size of div which contains svg text element

Tags: html, text, svg

```
<div id="maindiv" style="height:60px;width:100px;border:1px solid black;float:left">
    <svg width="100%" height="20">
    <text x="28" y="18" style="text-anchor: start">somedynamictext</text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

I want to set width of maindiv so that it can properly contain somedynamictext.
Number of somedynamictext can be dynamic.

Can I show ... in svg text element?

As per comments I did following

```
<div id="maindiv" style="height:60px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid black">
    <div id="MATCH" style="height:60px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid black;float:left">
        <svg width="100%" height="20">
            <text x="28" y="18">MATCH</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="REGULAR" style="height:60px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid black;float:left">
        <svg width="100%" height="20">
            <text x="28" y="18">REGULAR</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="EXPRESSION" style="height:60px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid black;float:left">
        <svg width="100%" height="20">
            <text x="28" y="18">EXPRESSION</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="MATCH1" style="height:60px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid black;float:left">
        <svg width="100%" height="20">
            <text x="28" y="18">MATCH1</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="REGULAR1" style="height:60px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid black;float:left">
        <svg width="100%" height="20">
            <text x="28" y="18">REGULAR1</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="EXPRESSION1" style="height:60px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid black;float:left">
        <svg width="100%" height="20">
            <text x="28" y="18">EXPRESSION1</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="MATCH2" style="height:60px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid black;float:left">
        <svg width="100%" height="20">
            <text x="28" y="18">MATCH2</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="REGULAR2" style="height:60px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid black;float:left">
        <svg width="100%" height="20">
            <text x="28" y="18">REGULAR2</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="EXPRESSION2" style="height:60px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid black;float:left">
        <svg width="100%" height="20">
            <text x="28" y="18">EXPRESSION2</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

I cannt reduce size of divs based on text length.

Comment: the div will do this by default, it's the `100px` inline style that is stopping it, just remove the width style on the div, div's be default have 100 width (block level)

Comment: Take off the width and set `display:inline-block` and it should just scale to fit whatever's inside it?

Comment: edited post after applying comments

Comment: Try also removing the `width="100%"` from `<svg ...` tag, and instead adding inline style `style = "width: auto;"`

Comment: @Ravi, it also did not work

Answer (score 1):

you can get the height and width of each svg element by using

```
var svgCoord=svg.getBoundingClientRect();
var svgHeight=svgCoord.height;
```

then set the height of all svg element by to maindiv.

document.getElementById("maindiv").setAttribute("height","sum of heights of all svg");